# Regular Expression - Two Digit Range (23-79)?

Tags: regex

I have been reading the regex questions on this site but my issue seems to be a bit different.  I need to match a 2 digit number, such as 23 through 75.  I am doing this on an HP-UX Unix system.  I found examples of 3 - 44 but or any digit number, nothing that is fixed in length, which is a bit surprising, but perhaps I am not understand the variable length example answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want a regex here? It seems like conversion to an integral type followed by integer comparison may be more appropriate. Especially if the range can change in the future.

Comment: Let me second @Paulpro's recommendation -- while a regex *can* do this, it's a poor (I'm tempted to say "terrible") tool for the job.

Comment: What's wrong with `23 <= the_number <= 75`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin If REGEX is so horrible, then why would it be included in things such as ed, sed, awk, grep, and most text editors? It is itself a pattern matching language. Just because you may have difficulty making it work for you doesn't mean that other people can't use it to do [almost] everything in a command line.

Comment: @Paulpro if they're using the RegEx in the command line the regex can change when they type out a new command if they know what they're doing. The OP is asking for an example on HP-UX. If you can provide any other methods on HP-UX that don't use Regex, please share.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid while this seems like it would make sense, you would need to write an `if` statement depending on the language the OP is using to execute their pattern matching.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I'm not familiar with HP-UX, but he could be doing this on any command-line right? I'm pretty sure you can install a shell like bash on HP-UX. It seems more intuitive to me that if it's in some script, then when the range changes all that needs to be changed is the boundaries of the range in the code, not a regular expression. If it's not in a script and is just a one-time deal than then the regex is a perfectly valid way to do it in my opinion. You're answer is a very good answer for the OP's question, by the way :)

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: What part of "for the job" didn't you understand? Some of us are actually professionals who care about things like readability and maintainability, not just the ability to hack out something that works for some particular situation under some specific circumstance.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sorry you're mistaken sir. There are thousands of people who use Regex daily for pattern matching in their professions. I happen to be one of them. What would you suggest "for the job" under HP-UX?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: You still haven't explained what part of "for the job" you didn't understand, but *have* made it even more clear that you simply don't understand the concept. HP-UX is almost entirely irrelevant here -- it's a fairly garden-variety UNIX with all the usual tools. Of course, since the OP hasn't explained what job he's really doing, it's impossible to say with any certainty what's right, even though he's said enough to make it 100% clear that a regex is the wrong choice.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If you're only talking about "the job" in reference to what Paulpro said then I see what you're saying this would not be the best approach for this. I didn't make any assumptions when I was trying to provide a broad blanket of answers and thought of probably 50 ways that Regex would be valid given different situations. The OP didn't clarify what this was for (or what it was used in for that matter). He may be using `vi` for all we know. Outside of Paul's guestimation "regex is a terrible tool for the job" seems unfounded.  I have an HP-UX vm myself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're not indicating whether this is in addition to any other characters (or in the middle of a larger string), I've included the logic here to indicate what you would need to match the number portion of a string. This should get you there. We're creating a range for the second numbers we're looking for only allowing those characters. Then we're comparing it to the other ranges as an `or`:

```
(2[3456789]|[3456][0-9]|7[012345])
```

As oded noted you can do this as well since sub ranges are also accepted (depends on the implementation of REGEX in the application you're using):

```
(2[3-9]|[3-6][0-9]|7[0-5])
```

Based on the title you would change the last 5 to a 9 to go from 75-79:

```
(2[3-9]|[3-6][0-9]|7[0-9])
```

If you are trying to match these numbers specifically as a string (from start to end) then you would use the modifiers `^` and `$` to indicate the beginning and end of the string.

There is an excellent technical reference of Regex ranges here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

If you're using something like grep and trying to match lines that contain the number with other content then you might do something like this for ranges thru 79:

```
grep "[^0-9]?(2[3-9]|[3-6][0-9]|7[0-9])[^0-9]?" folder
```

Comment: Could be shortened to `(2[3-9]|[3-6][0-9]|7[0-5])`

Comment: Right. I've ran into instances where this doesn't work in every implementation but according to the standard it should.

Comment: this will return true if you pass 2345

Comment: @RobinVanPersi we're using the `|` which means or and we're using the `[]` brackets to indicate allowed characters.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi the OP didn't indicate if this was in the middle of a string or not.

Comment: To all of you who offered answers, my sincere thanks. The 3 part range answers work. My apologies, I should have included that what I am doing is selecting files for an SCP operation. I am selecting files for SCP file transfer and they are in the middle of a string. Up till now, I have been having to make multiple SCP runs, as I could not figure out how to break it out.  Again THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 4):

This tool is exactly what you need: <s>Regex_For_Range</s>

From 29 to 79: `\b(2[3-9]|[3-7][0-9])\b`

From 29 to 75: `\b(29|[3-6][0-9]|7[0-5])\b`

And just for fun, from 192 to 1742: `\b(19[2-9]|[2-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-6][0-9]{2}|17[0-3][0-9]|174[0-2])\b` :)

Comment: The tool has credentials prompt right now, do you know the owners?

Comment: @weston Too bad! I'll contact them to know the reason of this authentication and I come back to you.

Comment: Well if you know them, maybe you could convince them to open source it. Post on github, or on here

Answer (score 2):

If I want 2 digit range 0-63

```
/^[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]|6[0-3]$/
```

1. [0-9] will allow single digit from 0 to 9
2. [0-5][0-9] will allow from 00 to 59
3. 6[0-3] will allow from 60 till 63

This way you can take Regular Expression for any Two Digit Range

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes of numbers you want to match:

- the digit 2, followed by one of the digits between 3 and 9
- one of the digits between 3 and 7, followed by any digit

**Edit:**  Well, that's the title's range (23-79).  Within your question (23-75), you have three:

- the digit 2, followed by one of the digits between 3 and 9
- one of the digits between 3 and 6, followed by any digit
- the digit 7, followed by one of the digits between 0 and 5

Comment: Almost - up to `75`, not `79`.

Comment: @Oded The op wrote 79 in the subject and then 75 in the body of the post. It's unclear which he really wants.

Comment: Apologies for the typo in the title example, the two numbers were examples, the key point was only 2 digits.  But I understand what you mean, 79 does fit the whole range of [3-7][0-9], the 75 was more accurate in that I could not always fill the whole range.  Thus, the 3 part range answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, here is a solution for generating the string from the accepted answer in javascript.  You can click "Run Code Snippet" to enter your own bounds and get your own string.

```js
function regexRangeString(lower,upper){
  let current=lower;
  let nextRange=function(){
    let currentString=String(current);
    let len=currentString.length;
    let string="";
    let newUpper;
    for(let digit=0;digit<len;digit++){
      let index=len-digit-1;
      let lower=Number(currentString[index]);
      let thisString="";
      for(let u=9;u>=lower;u--){
        let us=currentString.substring(0,index)+u+currentString.substring(index+1,len);
        if(Number(us)<=upper){
          if(lower==u){
            thisString=lower;
          }
          else{
            thisString=`[${lower}-${u}]`;
          }
          currentString=currentString.substring(0,index)+u+currentString.substring(index+1,len);
          break;
        }
      }
      if(thisString!="[0-9]"){
        string=currentString.substring(0,index)+thisString+string;
        break;
      }
      else{
        string=thisString+string
      }
    } 
    current=Number(currentString)+1;
    return string
  }

  let string=""
  while(current<upper){
    string+="|"+nextRange(current);
  }
  string="("+string.slice(1)+")";
  return string
}


let lower=prompt("Enter Lower Bound")
let upper=prompt("Enter Upper Bound")
alert(regexRangeString(lower,upper))
```

For example:

```
regexRangeString(72,189)
```

generates the following output string:

```
(7[2-9]|[8-9][0-9]|1[0-8][0-9])
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
/^([2][3-9]|[3-6][0-9]|[7][0-5])$/
```

`^` and `$` will make it strict that it will match only 2 numbers, so in case that you have `i.e 234` it won't work.

Comment: Additionally this will not work if they're using something like `grep` to match a line containing the numbers they're searching for.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ - no my friend I didn't down vote your answer. It took me more than 5 mins to test the requirements then posted it then I JUST checked your answer.