# Java Regex to Match a Number Within a Range

Tags: java, regex, range

I'm trying to craft a Java regular expression to identify if a number (which I don't know until execution time) is within a range (and that range I also don't know until execution time).

Specifically, I'm trying to use Cisco's PRIME compliance module to validate my switch has no inactive VLANs (for this question, a VLAN is just a number), but PRIME uses Java regular expression syntax.

I know that the specific switch command I'm evaluating uses a syntax like:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,20,37,45,90-101,300-502,904-2044
```

How, then, can I tell if VLAN "x" is in any of those ranges?

- If x = 20, it should match.
- If x = 90, it should match.
- If x = 900, it should fail.
- If x = 1043, it should match.

Any ideas?

Edit: Unfortunately, the RegEx listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721325/regular-expression-two-digit-range-23-79) is for ranges that are known; the examples are all hard-coded ranges. I need something that takes an unknown x, y, and z, where all x, y, and z might possibly be 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits, and matches if z is between x and y when written as "x-y".

Is there a way to take the string "x-y", parse it into \1 and \2 that are understood to be numbers, and match if (z >= \1 && z <= \2)?

I've tried looking at things like lookahead and lookbehind and crazy/obscure Java-compatible regex structures, but my head quickly got spun into the 4th dimension.

Comment: Does this have to be done with a regex?

Comment: Yeah, why not try a more regular expression? I think a regular expression is fine to parse the ranges. But the checking if a value is in the range is certainly not. Sorry, could not resist the joke.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression - Two Digit Range (23-79)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721325/regular-expression-two-digit-range-23-79)

Comment: Unfortunately, the RegEx listed at that possible dup are for ranges that are known; the examples are all hard-coded ranges.  I need something that takes an unknown x, y, and z, where all x, y, and z might possibly be 1, 2, 3, or 4 digits, and matches if z is between x and y when written as "x-y".

Comment: is there a way to take the string "x-y", parse it into \1 and \2 that are understood to be numbers, and return true if (z >= \1 && z <= \2)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this should be done with a regular expression. Personally I'd use a regex to check if it's the right format, i.e. check if the string matches `"VLAN ([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)(,([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?))*"`, then split the latter part on the commas and use integer parsing from there, depending on if there is a '-' in there or not you can check the ranges.

For instance like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gcb9pm7f/15/

```
function testRanges()
{
  var str = document.getElementById("textField").value;
  var test = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberField").value);

  str = str.toUpperCase(); // VLAN big
  var regex = /^VLAN ([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)(,([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?))*$/g;
  if (regex.test(str))
  {
    str = str.substring(5, str.length); // remove 'VLAN'
    var splitArray = str.split(',');
    for (var idx = 0; idx < splitArray.length; idx++)
    {
      var rangeStr = splitArray[idx];
      if (rangeStr.includes('-'))
      {
        // range, check both values.
        var a = parseInt(rangeStr.split('-')[0]);
        var b = parseInt(rangeStr.split('-')[1]);
        if (a > b)
        {
          if (test >= b && test <= a) return true; // range is inclusive
        }
        else // a <= b
        {
          if (test <= b && test >= a) return true; // range is inclusive
        }
      }
      else // not a range, single value
      {
        if (parseInt(rangeStr) === test) return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false; // no match or regex not matching.
}
```

Adjust to your programming language as needed. Should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Thanks FalcoGer.  Unfortunately, although I'm working with an application that accepts Java regular expressions, I'm not working with a Java interpreter or compiler.  I agree a function would be the right approach in principle, but all I have available to me is a RegEx parser that accepts two inputs - (1) a Java-like syntax, and (2) an string to match against - with a binary match/no-match output.  for examnple, this is an interesting start: [ ,]foo[,$] (with foo being the number to match), but having to match against a range really throws things off.

Comment: Well, sorry. I though I could help. What a convoluted setup you have.